# Deserilalize JObject from a stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net

In my application, I receive a `JObject` instance from the caller, the `JObject` will contain its own schema which I will validate, then I need to serialize into a stream, and deserialize it back at some point.

Here is the code for serialization and deserialization.

```
JObject obj; // comes from caller

await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, obj, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
stream.Position = 0;

var resp = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JObject>(stream);
```

However, this fails with error because `JObject` inherits from `JToken`, which is an abstract class.

> The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: To be clear, are you receiving a normal entity serialized as JSON that you want to create a JObject from, or is the entity you are receiving literally a serialized JObject? If the latter, that is .. unusual

Comment: It is the latter. I could take the input as an object, but then I will need to convert it to JObject anyway for schema validation.

Comment: At which command does it fail? `SerializeAsync` or `DeserializeAsync`?

Comment: DeserializeAsync

Comment: You are trying to deserialize a `JObject` which is from Json.NET using System.Text.Json.  That's not going to work.  If you are going to use System.Text.Json, deserialize to [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-6.0) and work with MSFT's [`System.Text.Json.Nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes?view=net-6.0) JSON DOM.

Comment: Or, use Newtonsoft consistently and serialize from and to the stream as shown [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).